# Django - Passing iteratable data from 2 related models to template

Tags: django, list, models

I have 2 models which look like this,

```
class OnlineTest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)

class OnlineTestProgress(models.Model):
    examinee = models.ForeignKey(MSchoolMateUser)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(OnlineTest)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
```

Inside of my template I want to show the user all the tests and their status. So, if the test status in the OnlineTestProgress model is COMPLETE, it will be a green row and if it is NOT TAKEN it will be a red row.

This requires me to iterate over 2 models and I am not able to do this.

For m tests and n users, the OnlineTestProgress model will have m.n entries while the OnlineTest model will have m entries.

I considered writing a function in the OnlineTest model but not sure if it the right approach.

Thank You for your time. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: "This requires me to iterate ove 2 models and I am not able to do this." What? Why not?

Comment: I am fairly new to django and the issue I am having is combining the data of two models such that I can iterate over them using a loop.

Comment: Sounds like you want `OnlineTestProgress.objects.filter(examinee=request.user)` which can then be filtered by the value of `complete`, then? Not sure if that filter will match because I don't know what your `MSchoolMateUser` looks like.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I need but suppose the OnlineTest model has 4 tests A, B, C, D but the user has only appeared in 2 (A, D). In the view, I want to show A and D as green and B and C as red which requires objects that carry information from both models together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to iterate over two models? It seems like you just need to iterate over OnlineTestProgress?

If OnlineTestProgress only has taken tests, then just add all of the tests that aren't in OnlineTestProgress on the back end

or just iterate over OnlineTest and check if each one is in OnlineTestProgress by passing all OnlineTest in OnlineTestProgress as a list called taken_list and do

```
{% for test in OnlineTest %}

    {% if test in taken_list %} [make the row green] {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The OnlineTestProgress model will have entries only for Tests that have been taken. I also want to show tests which have not been taken by the user yet.

Comment: on the backend, add all of the non-taken tests to the list of OnlineTestProgress with complete as false

Comment: @bryan60 that is the plan if there is no better way of doing it. I am looking to find a way that is more efficient than this.

Comment: doing this in the template would be far less efficient.

Comment: Thank You so much for this response. It is exactly what I was looking for.